# what is the right way to design the table in a database?

Tags: mysql

i want to know what is the right way to do it .

We have area which can be  `northamerica`, `southamerica`

we have goelocations which can be `slc`, `murry`, `peru`, `mexico`

so, one area can have many  geolocations.

table for this is

```
ID      Area    Geolocation  
1       NA      slc  
2       NA      murry  
3       SA      peru  
4       SA      mexico
```

If number of area and geolocation are very limited and not expected to grow do you see a problem in this type of design vs table with FK like below

Area table

```
ID      Area  
1       NA  
2       SA
```

Geolocation table

```
ID    Geolocation     AreaID  
1       slc            1  
2       mexico         2  
3       peru           2
```

which one will be easy to query and use in a php application?

Comment: thanks for the help .. the AREA and GEOLOCATIONS are not growing and are static(data will never be added to these tables.) which one is the best way to design the table with or with out foreign keys and why and why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though denormalization doesn't cost a lot because, as you say, the geolocation set is small and stable, it's still worth having a normalized table (as with your second option). You may decide to add (say) `centralamerica` or other regions. Or you may need to change the encoding used. The whole point of normalization is to make it easier to deal with changes you did *not* expect, not just the ones you can foresee.

The performance penalty for lookups is very small (if there is any at all). Updates will be easier and the data base will probably be smaller with an FK-based schema.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements, if you want more flexibility you could have two lookup tables (Area and Geolocation) and a 'mapping' table where you create different configurations of area/geolocation.

That would give you more flexibility to do different mappings without affecting existing data, though looking at the data you probably don't require it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple one-to-many relationship between the `AREA` and `GEOLOCATION` tables.  Any relational database could handle such a thing.  Add a foreign key to `GEOLOCATION` that points back to the `AREA` primary key and you're in business.  Don't forget to add an index to the `GEOLOCATION` foreign key column.

Comment: thanks for the help .. the AREA and GEOLOCATIONS   are not growing and are static(data will never be added to these tables.) which one is the best way to design the table with or with out foreign keys and why and why not.

Comment: I think I've made it clear: with foreign keys.  You want the referential integrity and normalization.

Comment: I think you're missing OP's question. He knows about foreign keys and is asking about the pros and cons of a denormalized schema under the stated assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and is fine. My rule for denormalization is, if I have a reason, it's enough of a reason. So, as long as you have a reason for such denormalization, then proceed.

The above design is not likely to make your queries more complicated. In fact, it might simplify them. It's just not optimized for asking questions like "What are the areas?"

Instead of this (normalized):

```
SELECT *
FROM areas
```

You have to do this (denormalized):

```
SELECT DISTINCT area
FROM geolocation
```

And what if there are areas that don't have a row in `geolocation` yet? How will you know about them?

Comment: A view can make the queries as simple for the normalized schema as for the denormalized one. I don't see any other reasons for denormalization in this case.

Comment: @TedHopp, good point, not considering performance, of course.